# Xcode 13 beta: "xcrun: error: Failed to locate 'instruments'"

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, ios-simulator

*Please note*, I'm looking for `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments` util (lower-case), not the `Instruments` app which can be found in `Xcode.app/Contents/Applications`.

---

I have both `Xcode12` and `Xcode13-beta-5` on my computer.
When run `xcrun instruments -w <device id>`, Xcode13 says `xcrun: error: Failed to locate 'instruments'`.

---

Locating the "instruments" in Xcode12:

```
olia@Olhas-MacBook-Pro % ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/*instruments* 

# output ✅
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
```

Locating the "instruments" in Xcode13:

```
olia@Olhas-MacBook-Pro % ls /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/*instruments* 

# output ❌      
zsh: no matches found: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/*instruments*
```

Here, `Xcode-beta.app` is Xcode13, and `Xcode.app` is Xcode12.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no "instruments" util because it was deprecated in `Xcode12`, and in `Xcode13` it seems to be removed.

Apple recommends using `xcrun xctrace` instead of `xcrun instruments` in Xcode12.
But as command `xcrun instruments -w` is for pre-launching Simulator, `xctrace` doesn't apply there.

We can run smth like

```
open -a Simulator.app --args -CurrentDeviceUDID <device id>
```

Answer (score 1):

haha ~, I copied Xcode 's instruments to Xcode13 's /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ , then run react-native run-ios successful.

Answer (score 0):

For me I needed to upgrade react-native using:

```
yarn upgrade react-native
```