# React-Native xcrun: error: Failed to locate 'instruments' in Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode13

`instruments` command-line tool has been removed in Xcode 13 and Apple asks to use `xctrace` instead.
But I'm not sure how I can fix it while running the React-Native project on the terminal.

`npx react-native run-ios --device "iPhone"`

Actually, I see the following errors.

```
xcrun: error: Failed to locate 'instruments'.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
error Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68872891/xcode-13-beta-xcrun-error-failed-to-locate-instruments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it has been removed in xcode 13 you have two options. You can upgrade your RN version to `0.65.x` where this issue is fixed or downgrade to xcode 12.

Comment: I was able to run ```npx react-native run-ios --device "iPhone"``` after installing Xcode 14 and React-Native 17. Thanks.